# Graphic in foot, how to position

Tags: graphics, positioning, footnotes, geometry

I need to put a Logo in the footnote of every page. It works so far, but the Logo is positioned very high, and sometimes it's very close to the text. I need to either position the logo lower or make the text end higher. (I would prefer the logo being lower) I tried changing the geometry setting, but that just makes everything go higher. I used fancyfoot to get the logo in.
I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.

That's my commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[ 
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=black,
linkcolor=black
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=3cm, bottom=30mm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}Stylepakete
\setlength{\headheight}{1.1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\footskip}{2\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logotransp.png}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcommand{\zB}{z.\,B. }
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\f}{\textbf}%Fettschreiben
\newcommand{\gr}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.6,0}}
\setlength\parindent{0ex}
\newcommand{\uu}[1]{\f{\gr{\large{#1}}}\\}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\gr}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\gr}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\gr}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{\gr}
\apptocmd{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\-\do\f\do\m}{}{}
```

Comment: `geometry` has the option `footskip` and you can use `\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=3cm, bottom=30mm,footskip=4cm]{geometry}` for example.

Comment: You can lower the graphic: `\fancyfoot[L]{\raisebox{-1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logotransp.png}}}`

Comment: BTW, it's called the footer or just foot, not a footnote.

Comment: Thank you! I did what Ulrike Fischer suggested and it works :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps you could turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lower the graphic:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{\raisebox{-1cm}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logotransp.‌​png}}}
```